# How to change the image in the list view?

Tags: android, listview

I need to change mt pic after click..

```
 public View getView(final int position, View itemListView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (itemListView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            itemListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lessons_single_item_details,null);

            itemListView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reading);
            holder.btn_reminders =(ImageView) itemListView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Reminders);

            itemListView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) itemListView.getTag();
        }      
        holder.btn_reminders.setFocusable(false);
        holder.btn_reminders.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        holder.btn_reminders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.btn_reminders.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
            }
        });

        return itemListView;
    }

     private class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView btn_reminders;
    }
```

[select image for change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekx4S.jpg)

[after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQiY3.jpg)

Comment: You have to store the value of the clicked items in yours arraylist and than after make the check in yours getView() method , that is selected or not and show items in listview accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

just do one thing just add tag when you click on item that before you check your tag values if is true then set your selected drawable else set unselect drawable

```
    public View getView(final int position, View itemListView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (itemListView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        itemListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lessons_single_item_details,null);

        itemListView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reading);
        holder.btn_reminders =(ImageView) itemListView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Reminders);

        itemListView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) itemListView.getTag();
    }
    if(holder.btn_reminders.getTag().equals(true))
    {
      holder.btn_reminders.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
    }
    else
    {
      holder.btn_reminders.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_un_star);
    }      
    holder.btn_reminders.setFocusable(false);
    holder.btn_reminders.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    holder.btn_reminders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.btn_reminders.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
            holder.btn_reminders.setTag(true);
        }
    });

    return itemListView;
}

 private class ViewHolder{
    public ImageView btn_reminders;
}
```